# Proving that this holomorphic function satisfies $|f'(0) |\leq|a|$

Tags: complex-analysis, solution-verification

This question was asked in complex analysis exam of previous year which I got from a senior and I am not able to solve it.

> Let $f: U\to U$ be a holomorphic function with $f(0) =0 =f(a)$ where $a \in  U\setminus\{0\}$ . Show that $|f'(0) |\leq |a|$.

Here $U$ is the unit disc. Schwartz lemma proves $|f'(0) | \leq  1$ and as $a<1$ , so it is proved easily.

Is this proof true?

If not then kindly tell me right proof.

Comment: $|f'(0)| < 1$ plus $|a| < 1$ does *not* imply that $|f'(0)| < |a|$.

Comment: $U$ is the disc?

Comment: What is $U$? ${}{}{}$

Comment: @copper.hat U is unit disc (open) with center origin

Comment: @Funktorality U is unit disc (open) with center origin

Comment: Btw, it is the Schwarz lemma, not Schwartz. It is named after the German mathematician  [Karl Hermann Amandus Schwarz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermann_Schwarz).

Comment: @MartinR you are right. Sorry for this stupid conclusion.

Comment: @MartinR will keep in mind.

Comment: @User: Do you know the automorphisms of the unit disk (which are Möbius transformations)? The idea is to apply the Schwarz lemma to $f(z)/T(z)$ where $T$ is a “suitable” Möbius transformation (using that $f(a) = 0$).

Comment: @MartinR no they were not covered in class.

Comment: Do you know Blaschke factorization?

Comment: No progress here?

Comment: @Caffeine Unfortunately they were also not covered in the course !!

Comment: @copper.hat no nothing till now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let
$$g(z):=\frac{f(z)(1-z\overline{a})}{z-a}$$
It's not hard to prove that $g:U\to U$ (hint: use the maximum modulus principle) and it is easy to see that $g(0)=0$. Thus, by Schwarz' lemma,

$$\begin{align*}1\ge &|g'(0)|=\left|\frac{f'(0)}{a}\right|\\
|a|\ge&|f'(0)|\end{align*}$$

Comment: +1 That was disturbingly simple!

Answer (score 1):

Another proof requires the knowledge of Blaschke products (I am aware the OP does not have the knowledge of this theory, but I state the answer here   for completeness): writing $a_j$ for the other zeros of $f$ in $U$, we have the Blaschke factorization (since $f$ is bounded)

$$f(z)=(\text{sup}_U|f|)z\frac{a}{|a|}\frac{z-a}{1-\overline{a}z}\prod_j\frac{a_j}{|a_j|}\frac{z-a_j}{1-\overline{a_j}z}\\
|f'(0)|=(\text{sup}_U|f|)\left|a\prod_j a_j\right|\le |a| $$

This proof has the advantage of giving us an exact result, not only an inequality.